# ant command not found when running from the path othe than ant installation directory

Tags: software-installation, executable

Actually I have installed Ant in rhel5 environment and set `ANT_HOME` variable in `/etc/profile` which points to `/usr/local/ant/bin` so when I execute command `echo $ANT_HOME` it gives correct path but I get `ant:command not found` when I tried executing it from other directory. I installed it using a tar named `apache-ant-1.7.1-bin.tar.gz` and untared it.

I tried the command below `ln -s /usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin /usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin/ant
ln: creating symbolic link /usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin/ant' to /usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin': File exists` but when I run ant it still says command not found

Comment: What directory is `ant` installed in? You may want to copy it (or use a symlink) so that it is in one of the directories in your $PATH. `/usr/local/bin` may be a good choice to copy it to.

Comment: Did you install from source or an rpm? You need the ant binary in your `$PATH` in addition to any `_HOME` environment vars, but a package should have done that for you, e.g. by having a symlink from /usr/local/bin/ant to /usr/local/ant/bin/ant.

Comment: Yeah I have added the required detail actually I am new to linux so can you give me some pointers about symbolic link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make it work:

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/apache-ant-1.7.1/bin

Make sure you update this PATH in your .bash_profile file or in any of the startup scripts under /etc/profile.d